# Побробнее о курантах

Tags: этимология

Хотелось бы узнать происхождение слова "куранты". И еще, это слово относится только к главным часам России или любым башенным часам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько значений этого слова:
1) большие комнатные часы с мелодичным звоном; музыкальный механизм в таких часах. Основу механизма составляет барабан с колками (штырьками), установленными в соответствии с нотами определённой мелодии;
2) башенные часы с музыкой. Кремлёвские куранты установлены в 1851-1852 гг. на 8-10-м ярусах Спасской башни (предполагают, что впервые часы здесь появились в 1491 г.). В разное время куранты исполняли марш Преображенского полка, мелодию Д. С. Бортнянского "Коль славен наш Господь в Сионе", песенку "Ах, мой милый Августин", "Интернационал", "Вы жертвою пали", произведения М. И. Глинки "Патриотическая песня" и "Славься". Сейчас звучит гимн России на музыку А. В. Александрова.
*Фр. courante - куранта (танец, сначала салонный), от danse courante - (букв.) бегущий танец, от courir - бежать < лат. currere - бежать. Музыка этого танца использовалась в старинных музыкальных часах.*
3)"Куранты" - "вестовые письма", придворно-дипломатическая рукописная газета в России в 17 в., содержавшая переводы и извлечения из иностранных газет и донесения русских представителей, посланников за границей. Предназначалась для царя, его приближённых и Посольского приказа. Редактор такой газеты назывался "курантельщик". [Фр. courant - текущий.] 
4)Курант - инструмент для растирания красок: глины, минеральных пигментов. В античности это были камни, в 5-6 вв. - механические мельницы, в 18-19 вв. - фарфоровый или мраморный пестик в ступке. [Фр. courant - бегущий.]

Comment: Родственное слово "прейскурант" букв. "текущие цены".